# How to set brightness and contrast and saturation of video/Image in directx

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I am playing video using custom allocator using directshow. I want to set brightness, contrast and saturation of a video. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can accomplish that:

1. Write/Find a Effect DMO that will handle brightness and contrast on you payload.
2. Get the [`IVMRMixerControl9`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390457(VS.85).aspx) from the renderer and call [`GetProcAmpControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390462(VS.85).aspx).

More information in [this MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/910ce129-a972-449b-bfe0-9c7d84b063d6) thread.